# Remove equal width constraint and resize button

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have two buttons in my app that have an equal width constraint.

[image]

I need to hide the right side button and resize the left one to fit the entire width of the screen.

I have tried the following (none of which worked):

1. Hide the right button, remove the equal width constraint
   programmatically,  then resize the left button's frame and, finally,
   call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`. Complete code below:

   ```
   self.btnRight.hidden = YES;

   [self.view removeConstraint:_btnWidthEqualConstraint];

    CGRect buttonFrame = self.btnLeft.frame;
    buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(300, 70);
    self.btnLeft.frame = buttonFrame;

    [self.btnLeft setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
   ```
2. Update the constraints:

   ```
   UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
   CGRect screenSize = screen.bounds;
   self.btnRight.hidden = YES;
   [self.btnRight updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
     make.width.equalTo(@(0));
   }];
   [self.btnLeft updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
       make.width.equalTo(@(screenSize.size.width-12));
   }];
   ```

How can I hide the right side button and resize the left one to fit the entire width of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UIStackView` with the following setup:

```
let leftButton = UIButton(type: .system)
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .system)

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [leftButton, rightButton])
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 8 // or whatever spacing you wish to have between the buttons
```

Then you can simply hide one button (`leftButton.isHidden = true`) and the other one takes the entire width.

*Of course you can do the whole setup in interface builder as well.*

Answer (score 1):

1. you can add width constraint on each one of buttons and set the width constraint >= 1
2. after that set all "equal constraints" **priority** to 1 and set width constraint **priority** to (for example) 1000
3. after that in .m file at your condition, you can set another width constraint because of priority :

self.yourButtonWidthConstraint.constant = yourWidth;